# Gnuplot: Setting major label x tics with xdata time doesn't plot data

Tags: gnuplot

When I `set xdata` and accompanying options to space out the xtics my data isn't plotted, but the graph window itself is displayed fine. Not using the `set xdata .... set timefmt` options however plots the datapoints but with the labels spaced too close.

This produces correct output but has the xtics too close for legibility [Link to output](http://djinnius.com/stock.svg):

```
set ylabel "% Change"
set logscale y
set yrange [0.9:2]
set ytics nomirror

set y2range [1:50]
set y2tics
set y2label "-List- Rank"

set xtics rotate
set xlabel "Date"

set title "-List- -Stock-"

set datafile separator "|"

#choose the svg terminal
set terminal svg  size 1600,900 font "Bitstream Vera Sans, 12" linewidth 1
#pipe the output to a file
set output "| cat >./stock.svg"
plot "< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ...'" using 
($2/31.8):xtic(1) with linespoints title "CPRT" , \
"< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ...'" using ($9/1472.33):xtic(1) with linespoints title "SP 500", \
"< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ... '" using ($3):xtic(1) axes x1y2 with points  title "CPRT Rank"
```

This does not plot the datapoints but has the xtics spaced legibly [Link to output](http://djinnius.com/stock2.svg):

```
set ylabel "% Change"
set logscale y
set yrange [0.9:2]
set ytics nomirror

set y2range [1:50]
set y2tics
set y2label "-List- Rank"

set xtics rotate
set xlabel "Date"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d"
set xtics nomirror
set xrange ["2013-01-16":"2014-04-23"]
#set the xtics to be one week (604800 seconds) apart for major tics
set xtics "2013-01-16",604800,"2014-04-23"

set title "-List- -Stock-"

set datafile separator "|"

#choose the svg terminal
set terminal svg  size 1600,900 font "Bitstream Vera Sans, 12" linewidth 1
#pipe the output to a file
set output "| cat >./stock.svg"
plot "< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ...'" using 
($2/31.8):1 with linespoints title "CPRT" , \
"< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ...'" using ($9/1472.33):1 with linespoints title "SP 500", \
"< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ... '" using ($3):1 axes x1y2 with points  title "CPRT Rank"
```

I'm not sure how gnuplot handles the data as I think that might be part of the problem. Datapoints are on Mondays and Wednesdays, but there may be times when the Monday datapoint is on a Tuesday instead.

Here is a snippet of code where you can see that the Monday 2/17 datapoint is on 2/18 due to the holiday.

```
2014-01-29|34.22||34.62|33.95|34.25|349000|34.25|1790.15|1790.15|1770.45|1774.2|3964020000|1774.2
2014-02-03|34.11||34.11|32.59|32.64|1438700|32.64|1782.68|1784.83|1739.66|1741.89|4726040000|1741.89
2014-02-10|33.84||34.03|33.56|33.94|416100|33.94|1796.2|1799.94|1791.83|1799.84|3312160000|1799.84
2014-02-12|34.69||34.86|34.46|34.73|746800|34.73|1820.12|1826.55|1815.97|1819.26|3326380000|1819.26
2014-02-18|34.25||34.43|33.75|33.81|1205200|33.81|1839.03|1842.87|1835.01|1840.76|3421110000|1840.76
2014-02-19|33.64||34.52|33.36|34.27|1085300|34.27|1838.9|1847.5|1826.99|1828.75|3661570000|1828.75
2014-02-24|34.82||35.57|34.72|35.36|1333400|35.36|1836.78|1858.71|1836.78|1847.61|4014530000|1847.61
2014-02-26|34.67||35.89|33.91|35.49|2035800|35.49|1845.79|1852.65|1840.66|1845.16|3716730000|1845.16
2014-03-03|36.26||36.43|35.83|36.16|467600|36.16|1857.68|1857.68|1834.44|1845.73|3428220000|1845.73
2014-03-05|36.56||36.83|36.3|36.78|431200|36.78|1874.05|1876.53|1871.11|1873.81|3392990000|1873.81
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variant of your plotting command, i.e.

```
plot "< sqlite3 ..." using ($2/31.8):xtic(1)
```

uses the row number as x-value and puts a label for every data point on the x-axis, which is taken from the first column.

In the second case you use the time data as y-value, but it should be `using 1:($2/31.8)`. So, the complete plotting command might look as follows:

```
plot "< sqlite3 db.sq3 'SELECT IBD50_CPRT_Master.Date, ...'" using 1:($2/31.8):1 with linespoints title "CPRT" , \
     "" using 1:($9/1472.33):1 with linespoints title "SP 500", \
     "" using ($3):1 axes x1y2 with points  title "CPRT Rank"
```

The `""` uses the same source as the previous plotting command.

And you don't need to pipe the output anywhere, `set output "stock.svg"` works fine.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. And thanks for the additional hints. Much appreciated.